# powershell exchange 2013 get-mailbox command

Tags: exchange, powershell

The get-mailbox command does not work on powershell exchange 2013. Does anyone know a replacement command?

I need to copy mail from a certain time period from one user to another.

Thanks

Comment: The Get-Mailbox cmdlet does work in 2013, but it sounds like you want New-MailboxExportRequest and New-MailboxImportRequest to export and import mail items.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I cant see a way to copy mail into another users mailbox with this feature, the Get-mailbox command used to allow this.

Comment: hi thanks very much just realised in combination with the new-mailboximportrequest it will do exacly what I wanted.